# how to make name search feature in flutter

Tags: flutter, search, filter

I'm having a problem doing a name search, where when I type the name of a user, it doesn't appear the way I want and doesn't filter according to the name I'm looking for.

```
List<Data> data = [];
List<Data> allData = [];
List<Data> _foundData = [];

@override
initState() {
_foundData = allData;
super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
_foundData.clear();
super.dispose();
}

void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
List<Data> results = [];
if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
  results = allData;
} else {
  results = allData
      .where(
        (user) => user.name!.toLowerCase().contains(
              enteredKeyword.toLowerCase(),
            ),
      )
       .toList();
 }
 setState(() {
  _foundData = results;
 });
 }`

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      appBar: const PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: CustomAppbar(
          title: 'Dosen',
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 16,
            top: 16,
            right: 16,
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        width: 1,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                        width: 1,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    hintText: 'Cari nama dosen...',
                    fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    filled: true,
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: greyColor,
                    ),
                    suffixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      color: greyColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              FutureBuilder<List<Data>>(
                future: ListDosenProvider.getDosen(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                      return Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                          // itemCount: allData.length,
                          // itemCount: _foundData.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14),
                              child: Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(8),
                                  ),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                                      spreadRadius: 1,
                                      blurRadius: 9,
                                      offset: const Offset(
                                        1,
                                        2,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Image.asset(
                                        'assets/images/user.png',
                                        width: 50,
                                      ),
                                      const SizedBox(
                                        width: 10,
                                      ),
                                      Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            snapshot.data![index].name
                                                .toString(),
                                            style: bold6,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            snapshot.data![index].prodi
                                                .toString(),
                                            style: regular6,
                                          ),
                                          const SizedBox(
                                            width: 8,
                                          ),
                                          const SizedBox(
                                            height: 5,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 30,
                                            width: 90,
                                            child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                                                launch(
                                                  'mailto:${snapshot.data![index].email.toString()}',
                                                );
                                              },
                                              icon: Icon(
                                                Icons.mail,
                                                size: 17,
                                                color: primaryColor,
                                              ),
                                              label: Text('Email',
                                                  style: bold6.copyWith(
                                                    color: primaryColor,
                                                  )),
                                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                backgroundColor: const Color(
                                                  0xffC5D5FF,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Center(
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/server.png',
                              height: 100,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Upsss... Server error!',
                            style: regular4,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: primaryColor),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I've been looking for a way and doing it according to the instructions above but it still doesn't work when I do a name search
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZxbI.png)

Comment: Can you add your code of `build` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `_foundData` to list data. In some case, if use enters search before load that may not work. So I filter the search result on every build by using `TextEditingController`, so that we can persist user input.

Replace you code with following..

```
  List<Data> allData = [];
  List<Data> _foundData = [];
  final searchController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _foundData.clear();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<Data> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.trim().isEmpty) {
      results = allData;
    } else {
      results = allData
          .where(
            (user) => user.name!.toLowerCase().contains(
                  enteredKeyword.trim().toLowerCase(),
                ),
          )
          .toList();
    }
    _foundData = results;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      appBar: const PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: CustomAppbar(
          title: 'Dosen',
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
            left: 16,
            top: 16,
            right: 16,
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                child: TextField(
                  onChanged: (value) => setState(() {}),
                  controller: searchController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        width: 1,
                        color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(
                        width: 1,
                        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    hintText: 'Cari nama dosen...',
                    fillColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                    filled: true,
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: greyColor,
                    ),
                    suffixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      color: greyColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              FutureBuilder<List<Data>>(
                future: ListDosenProvider.getDosen(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                      allData = snapshot.data!;
                      _runFilter(searchController.text);
                      return Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                          itemCount: _foundData.length,
                          // itemCount: allData.length,
                          // itemCount: _foundData.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14),
                              child: Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(8),
                                  ),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                                      spreadRadius: 1,
                                      blurRadius: 9,
                                      offset: const Offset(
                                        1,
                                        2,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Image.asset(
                                        'assets/images/user.png',
                                        width: 50,
                                      ),
                                      const SizedBox(
                                        width: 10,
                                      ),
                                      Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            _foundData[index].name.toString(),
                                            style: bold6,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            _foundData[index].prodi.toString(),
                                            style: regular6,
                                          ),
                                          const SizedBox(
                                            width: 8,
                                          ),
                                          const SizedBox(
                                            height: 5,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 30,
                                            width: 90,
                                            child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                                              onPressed: () {
                                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                                                launch(
                                                  'mailto:${_foundData[index].email.toString()}',
                                                );
                                              },
                                              icon: Icon(
                                                Icons.mail,
                                                size: 17,
                                                color: primaryColor,
                                              ),
                                              label: Text('Email',
                                                  style: bold6.copyWith(
                                                    color: primaryColor,
                                                  )),
                                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                backgroundColor: const Color(
                                                  0xffC5D5FF,
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Center(
                            child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/images/server.png',
                              height: 100,
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 20,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Upsss... Server error!',
                            style: regular4,
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  return Expanded(
                    child: Center(
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(color: primaryColor),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much it worked, i really appreciate you. thank you for your dedication and spare time, I learn a lot from you.